# Индекс не для цифр(INT)

Tags: оптимизация, индексы, mysql

Вот в базе MYSQL, для цифр(int) нужно ставить индекс, для быстрого перебора. А как же быть, если тип не int, а varchar например?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс нужно ставить, если по этому полю идет сравнение. Какого типа данное поле не столь важно, т.е. сравнение будет выполняться быстрее с использованием индекса, чем прямым перебором. Индексы можно ставить на простые конечные типы, а также на комбинацию полей.

Так вот, сравнивать строки всегда дольше, чем сравнивать числа. Кроме скорости сравнения индекс по строковому полю сказывается на размере индекса (ну и на размере базы, как следствие). В вашем случае в этом просто нет необходимости.

У вас в notifications.type содержатся служебные значения, и с точки зрения программы не важно что там будет число или строка. В любом случае пользователю эта информация без обработки не нужна, все равно нужна будет подстановка (например локализованная строка).

А, например, если у вас будет поиск по имени юзера `select * from users where username='Вася'`, то, конечно, тут деваться будет некуда, надо будет добавить индекс по полю username, и поиск будет выполняться быстрее.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, у меня SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = '123asdsd...' ну Вы поняли. Вот hash у меня имеет varchar(100), а к такому типу индекс не добавляется. Выдаёт #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'hash' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Для varchar(100) можно добавить индекс. Ваша ошибка говорит, что hash у вас типа text или blob. Для таких полей надо указывать индексируемую длину. Например:

    CREATE INDEX part_of_hash ON users (hash(100));

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, воо, спасибо!